# Is there any way to use a Wpf Label's Target without naming the target control?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Normally when you want to associate a Wpf Label with a target element you'd do the following:

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=FirstName}" Content="First Name:" />
<TextBlock Name="FirstName" ... />
```

I was wondering if there is any other way to do this without using a `Name` or `x:Name` property?

Comment: BTW - Normally that'd be a `TextBox`, not a `TextBlock` (since it needs something which accepts focus)

Comment: This is one of those moments where it is applicable to name a control.

Comment: I was wondering of a binding type of `NextElement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a named control and an `ElementName` binding is the standard approach to setting a label target.

The other approach would be to specifically set the `Target` property to a `UIElement`, which could be done in code behind for a generated UI, for example.